# Wit.ai recognizes numbers as location

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, wit.ai

We are facing the issue that wit.ai recognizes almost every number as a location. Sometimes even as a DateTime, but almost never as a number. We tried to teach it that 1 is a number, 2 is a number, etc., but it doesn't seem to pick that up, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Do you solve it ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We are not using Wit to detect numbers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a new bot app and just added one sentence with wit/number entity in the sample database and It works okay for me as you can see:

[image]

Maybe your problem is with other samples which make the tagging problem confusing for the algorithm behind wit.ai (probably a CRF or RNN based model). I suggest you to add many more samples with wit/number entity in them and check if it works.